# How to get the vscode theme color in vscode extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use some color used in current vscode theme in my extension. How do I get the colors?

In other words, I want to match the color of extension using original color with the base vscode windows in run-time of extension.

Comment: Do you want to get color once? Do you want to get all colors from theme to create your own? Do you want to get color in run-time from extension?

Comment: I want to get them in run-time in order to make matched color between current theme and the extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can reference  [workbench colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference):

```typescript
const color = new vscode.ThemeColor('badge.background');
```

That will give you reference to the color of the current theme's badge.

Note, that you cannot reference TM scope items: [#32813](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32813)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-namethemecoloraspan-classcodeitem-id244themecolorspan

Comment: Thank you. I've understood it. Indeed it seems to be correct structure that can get only reference.

Comment: Is there a way to have the real color behind the ThemeColor? [See issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34411).

Comment: No, no way yet.

Answer (score 9):

For accessing the theme color on the WebView context, there are css variables generated for all the [theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). For example, for getting:

```
editor.background
```

You can use the css variable:

```
var(--vscode-editor-background)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have your desired color scheme in your VS Code instance, run the `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings` command. This will generate a color theme file that you can then publish in your own extension

Comment: Thanks, it may be indirect way but it seems to get color from the code of extension in run-time of extension.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this in my vscode extension:

```js
function getCssColor(themeColor: ThemeColor | undefined): string {
  // @ts-expect-error id is aprivate class member but there's no other API currently https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34411#issuecomment-329741042
  return `var(--vscode-${(themeColor.id as string).replace('.', '-')})`
}
```

Pretty hacky, but hey, it works!

---

For context, in case that helps someone, I use the above to create an HTML icon I end up throwing in the Markdown of the tooltip showin when hovering a TreeItem.

```js
`<span style="color:${getCssColor(icon.color)};">$(${icon.id})</span>`
```