# How do I make all HTML attributes italicized in VSCode? Is it possible?

Tags: html, attributes

Thanks for helping. How do I make all HTML attributes (ie the word type=), italicized in VSCode? Is it possible? I meant like to change the theme. You know how some themes have italicized attributes? type=, class=, id=, I just want these guys italicized in the theme.

Answer (score 8):

VS Code's [syntax color themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) can specify a `fontStyle` in addition to the color of syntax scopes. To make text italic, you'd want to set `"fontStyle": "italic"`

This example [`editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#syntax-colors) uses `fontStyle` to make some html attributes italic:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's an [example of how to set `fontStyle` in an actual color theme](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/700780d927135cd78c1c653da63b8fd896c72bee/extensions/theme-abyss/themes/abyss-color-theme.json#L81).

`entity.other.attribute-name` is only an example scope. You may need to tweak the scope or style multiple scopes based on your specific needs

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tag `<i>inert italicized content here</i>` example:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <i>this stuff is italicized</i>
  </body>
</html>`
```

another good tag is `<em></em>` used to emphasize the tags. [Here's a great website I like to use.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp)

edit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117621/how-to-get-the-vscode-theme-color-in-vscode-extensions)

Comment: I meant like to change the theme. You know how some themes have italicized attributes? type=, class=, id=, I just want these guys italicized in the theme.

Comment: To be honest, i've never seen any "themed" attributes, classes, or Ids. I'm a bit confused... Don't downvote him. He's just new.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=markfknight.monokai-operator-theme  see how this theme has italicized key words? I want the attributes to be italicized for my theme. I want to edit it. Is it possible?