# How to change the colours of the extensions of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, tabnine

The extension Tabnine takes the background color of the sidebar of my theme of vscode, but just that one. Not any other colour. I tried all color configurations in [vs code theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) and none seems to work, only the background. Also this extension doesnt include any option settings for the colours.

I need I can configure at least font colour that shows in white to make it easily readable.

[image: How tabnine looks]

Comment: why not create an issue at the tabnine repo

Comment: because I am not sure is something I am missing, some configuration, or is something that happens to every extension, or is just this one

Comment: I'll bet they're just not using https://stackoverflow.com/a/56759634/11107541. which is weird because glancing at the extension code, there are places where they do. so it's not like they don't know about it. if you do raise an issue ticket, please add a link to it here